# Downvoting questions that were voted to close

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I asked a question on SO, [How to get a user's account picture in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59603257/how-to-get-a-users-account-picture-in-linux)? a kind user told me that it suits Unix and Linux and not SO. I respected and agreed his opinion, and closed my own question. Five minutes later, I saw that a person has downvoted the question. Is this fair?

I didn't delete the question, cause I previously received a warning that "actively deleting a question might result in ban of account", as I had deleted some of my previous questions.

People thinking that the downvoter couldn't have known the 'vote to close', it was there in comments of the question. So it makes me conclude that, that the respected downvoter has just like that downvoted the question without even reading its contents. Wow...

Now my question is from whom can I recover the lost reputation, for people with 80K points, it hardly matters, not in my case, a beginner with 320 points?

Comment: "Is this fair?" ... people are free to vote like why want to. If they see your question unfit for the Stack Overflow platform, then they can downvote. If the question is closed or not doesn't matter.

Comment: Close voting and downvoting often go hand-in-hand. Close voting means a question is not answerable or off-topic on Stack Overflow, downvoting means a question is not useful or does not show research effort. Questions that are not answerable are often not useful or don't show research effort. Note that deleting off-topic questions is often better than leaving them around to accumulate downvotes only for them to get auto-deleted later, so I recommend you do delete off-topic questions, and of course try to check if they're on-topic before asking next time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is one case where it's best to just delete it. Off-topic questions are not meant to be improved or answered, so they are only likely to attract downvotes until it's deleted. The downvotes *are* to be expected here, since off-topic questions are perceived as not useful.

In the event that this led you to a question ban, you will have to look for other on-topic questions of your own to improve, or take advantage of the 6-month question grant. This is all described in this relevant [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/1233251).

In the future, please keep in mind of [what topics are considered on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.

Comment: Note that to be eligible for deletion by high-rep users a question needs to have score -3. So if the author does not for some reason delete their really off-topic question in popular tags it is expected that such question collects at least 3 downvotes to enable early deletion by users.