# Stuck in a question ban, but I don't know why

Tags: support, post-ban, help-center

i am stuck in a question ban and i don't know why

The help desk says

> Begin by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.

but I think my questions are fine you can check them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13029464/juls07?tab=questions), I am unaware of how to contact staff if even possible. I was going to ask a question on normal Stack Overflow but I cant anymore as I am question banned I believe it was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852073/how-to-compress-ram-fedora-wayland-latest-gnome-latest-3-36-3-wm-mutter?noredirect=1#comment111146575_62852073) but I removed it and asked elsewhere so I cannot improve my question as it no longer exists I don't know what to do and any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have 6 *deleted* questions with score <= 0 that are contributing to your [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/62852073) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/62382121) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/62076430) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/62052393) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/61861029) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/61023044).

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61766642/solved-mcp-918-fails-on-linux-kubuntu-20-04-solved ? That is not how questions are solved, you self answer them properly to include all the steps that "solved" it. So not all your questions are fine. Please go over the [Help Centre articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again. Also helpful to self evaluate your questions is using the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: You say you are trying to edit your questions but nor your [visible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13029464/juls07?tab=activity&sort=revisions) not your deleted ones have been edited by you since May. Is there something not working on your end that prevent your edit attempts to get saved?

Comment: @CodyGray [this][1] [1][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023044/how-to-redirect-user-based-on-user-agent-html-node-js] []this][2] [2][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052393/is-it-possible-to-change-distros-within-your-current-distro-without-loosing-data] [this][3] [3][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382121/mysql-vs-sqlite-witch-is-better-for-a-fluxbb-db] [and this][4] [4][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076430/deja-dup-restore-failed] all have a reason

Comment: I am merely providing you with links that, due to a Stack Overflow bug, may not be available to you. (We only show users their own deleted questions when they are less than 60 days old.) Giving you the links allows you to review each of them and make the appropriate decision about whether or not they are salvageable. Some of them aren't, and it's better to just forget about them. But they *are* contributing to your overall quality score, so it's good to be aware of them. I'll let other community members make suggestions about how to improve your questions.

Comment: Please read this if you can't ask new questions: **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)**

Comment: @CodyGray [this][1] [1][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023044/how-to-redirect-user-based-on-user-agent-html-node-js] []this][2] [2][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052393/is-it-possible-to-change-distros-within-your-current-distro-without-loosing-data] [this][3] [3][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382121/mysql-vs-sqlite-witch-is-better-for-a-fluxbb-db] [and this][4] [4][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076430/deja-dup-restore-failed] all have a reason 1:i posted this on Reddit and found the answer there 2:same as 1 3: same again 4:posted on super user (in comments)

Comment: It's kind of telling when a user on Stack Overflow cannot post links properly in comments. It means they haven't studied how to or they haven't read the instructions carefully enough [“**There are three ways to write links**. Each is easier to read than the last:”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: you have several questions belonging on SuperUser or Unix.SE in the pile of deleted questions, you have a few that are off-topic, and a few [lacking an MCVE by abusing the system meant to prevent paste sites](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61165995/6296561). There's 2 that look like SU questions, but that really are just lacking an MCVE

Comment: Of the ones you have left (from bottom to the top of the list when sorted by age), you have: A duplicate that's also borderline unclear, a question that's too broad and off-topic (possibly better on ServerFault), no MCVE (+ dead pastesite link), one I'm not sure about, but that's extremely borderline, two no MCVEs with a way too high focus on the OS (looks like SU/Unix.SE, is no MCVE), too broad/no MCVE, and the last one looks fine

Comment: Regarding the ones which are unsalvageable, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392679) is my recommendation from another question.

Comment: @juls07 Considering that most of your Stack Overflow questions seem to get answered when you repost them on Reddit, have you considered *just using Reddit* and cutting out the middleman? Then your question ban here becomes completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thats how you do it in posts sorry for not knowing how to put them in comments when i never post comments

Comment: @Zoe tons of my "deleted" questions were automatically deleted after 60 days of inactivity

Comment: @E_net4isoutofclosevotes thanks for the help one of the only people to actually help thanks

Comment: The deletion reason doesn't matter. They're also still off-topic whether they're deleted or not

Comment: @CodyGray nice try but its not what my questions needs thanks for trying though

Comment: @Zoe what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 18):

Okay, let's analyze and advice on some of these deleted questions that you claim you found an answer for elsewhere:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61023044

> I want my website to be able to redirect users based on their user-agent I want to redirect safari user by the way as my node.js website doesn't support safari

This doesn't read as a question about a programming problem. This is nothing more then a requirement. Don't mistake Stack Overflow for being an alternative search engine where others do the searching. I'm pretty sure sending HTTP responses based on HTTP requests have been covered before. Sharing the code, config and modules you're using and what exactly you can't get to work is essential in these type of questions.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052393

> the title says it all I want to change my distro to parrot home KDE I'm currently running Kubuntu

I'm about to post a quality filter feature request that will block any question that starts with *the title says it all*. There is nothing more to say after the title? Really? No research, no context, no attempt, no goal, no hurdles? But in the end you're right. The title says it all: That is not a programming problem at all. You can find what is on topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and there you'll find explicitly mentioned what is **off-topic**: *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic*.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62382121

> i run a website (from reddit)(Rule 2) and i want to know if SQLite3 specifically is better than mySQL i was looking at most databases and they mostly run on SQLite3 so witch is better

That is asking for an opinion and that type of questions is mentioned in [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). "Better" is so under-defined. Better for what? CPU cycles? How easy it is to setup? Size? Client tooling? Maximum load? Your website gets 1000 visitors per hour? Website and database run on the same site? MySQL and SQLite3 are vastly different database engines with different setup and usage scenarios. At best it is an architectural decision, not something that is solved on the internet.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62076430

> I made a backup of my home folder in Kubuntu 20.04 and, when I tried to restore it in parrot OS latest, it says *[...left out stack trace...]* I don't understand what this means. Can anyone help?

That is again something for Super User. It looks a bit unclear to me, but I'm not a Kubuntu user so maybe restoring is a one-click wonder that needs no context.

#### TL;DR

It looks like you take Stack Overflow as if it is any other forum, like Reddit, Quora, usenet. That is a mistake. Stack Overflow is scoped to be knowledge base of questions and answers about:

> a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

On top of that, we expect questions to have value for future visitors. That means that it is seldom enough to type your initial [brainwave](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brainwave) into the question textbox and hit enter. Besides [using the checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648) we expect users to do research, a lot of it, before you even consider posting a question. That is explained in [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

I think above guidance and links should give you enough leads to revisit your existing questions and improve by editing them. If that makes those questions valuable for others so they gather votes might help in getting yourself out of the quality ban. If not, you're rate limited to one question every six months. Make sure that question is awesome. You have plenty of time to prepare that one.

Comment: i do not treat stack overflow as a normal forum site i post my programming questions nad road blocks on stack overflow nothing like i would post on Reddit, Quora, usenet ect.

Comment: @juls nothing like on Reddit? But you ended up posting most of your Q's on Stack and reddit, according to you.... Something is off

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting your question you should edit them to make it more clear, detailed and on-topic as the Helpdesk message says. When you edit your question it will land into review queue and other community members can vote to reopen those questions.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I meant avoid deleting question at all cost.If you have found an answer somewhere(reddit etc) you can add that as an answer to your own question in stackoverflow and can accept your own answer

Comment: @juls07 To simplify: deleted questions do not raise the average score. If you have posted five questions of which two have scored 0 and three have each scored -1 that means you have a reputation of -6 (2 points are deducted per downvote), even if you delete the ones with a negative score, **the system** recognises that your *real* rep is -6. What can you do to rectify this situation? IMPROVE those questions that have negative scores. HOW? Follow the site's guidelines, do the RESEARCH, and explain what solutions you have tried.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, this is a markedly different tone than you take with such OPs on EL&U ;)

Comment: @DanBron on a technical site, which SO is, I would expect users to understand the voting system and the technicalities behind a question/answer ban. But the fact I keep seeing users, who consistently post low quality contributions,  ask time and time again how to overcome the ban, e.g. `what do you mean?` illustrates why that  message needs to be further clarified. And sometimes, the only way to do this is through bluntness.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Believe me, I know.  I am absolutely on the same wavelength.  I just wish you'd be so vehement about research on EL&U, too!