# How can I improve my "permanently" bad questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, post-ban, quality-improvement

I have a lot of questions on SO that have either no votes or a tasty sum of downvotes. I know there are a lot of questions concerning downvotes and how to improve questions, but I'll take it a step further:

How do I improve questions that have *already been condemned by the community*? I have questions that even *I* admit are just bad overall (due to my lack of research or searching the SO), and am currently banned from asking questions on SO. Looking at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), the guidelines suggest editing my questions to make them better, but that would be impossible in my case as my questions of late have been rather poor.

Comment: If you cannot improve them because they're just hopeless, then you can ask one every 6 months and make those really really good ones, and then perhaps *eventually* get out of the ban. In the meantime, you can post great Answers :)

Comment: Duplicate of: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/8967612) Specifically the part that says: _"If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one six months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will remain in effect, and you'll have to wait another six months to ask your next question."_

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392678

Comment: You reap what you sow I'm afraid. There is no pleading to an algorithm, it treats everyone equally fairly harshly. Lucky for you, Stack Overflow is not "the web". Plenty of other places to ask questions, and in those places the questions you yourself label "rather poor" might just be perfectly acceptable, can be discussed and people can give you a little mentoring. If only people wouldn't be so dead set on putting all their questions on Stack Overflow, it is so unnecessary.

Comment: For a list of alternatives to Stack Overflow, see e.g. [this answer to *Why are opinion-based questions banned?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409384/why-are-opinion-based-questions-banned/409391#409391).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the feedback! _(this is the reason why I love the Stack)_

Comment: Also, I was unaware someone who was question banned could ask questions every 6 months, thanks for the heads up.